# Pigeonholing finite aliens on a spaceship

Tags: puzzle, pigeonhole-principle

> There is a group of finite aliens on a spaceship. Show that there are at least $2$ aliens who know the same number of aliens on the spaceship.

I was given a hint, and that was to use the pigeonhole principle. I think I can visually see it but I am unsure how to show it.

Comment: Note that if there's only $1$ alien, then it isn't true.

Comment: @Richard Carpenter There are several versions of the pigeonhole principle. Which one are you familiar with?

Comment: I am familiar with the idea that if theirs 10 pigeons and 9 holes, then theirs at least 2 pidgeons in 1 hole

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Let $n$ be the number of aliens on the ship. As noted in the comments, you must assume that $n\ge 2$. Suppose that A is an alien on the ship; how many of the others can it know? The largest possible answer is $n-1$, and the smallest is $0$.

- How many possibilities is that?
- Is it actually possible for one of the aliens to know $n-1$ of the others and another to know $0$?

Comment: So if their is 5 aliens on the ship, one of the aliens could know 4. But, then it is not possible for another to know 0 because one of the aliens already knows him.

Comment: @Richard: That’s right. And in that case the possible numbers for the other four aliens are $1,2,3$, and $4$. So there are $5$ aliens, each of whom knows $1,2,3$, or $4$ of the others, and therefore ... ? The case when one of the aliens knows none of the others is similar.

Comment: So therefore, at least two aliens know the same number of aliens in the spaceship. Suppose theirs $n$ aliens. Then the possible number of aliens a single alien could know is $n-1, n-2, n-3,...,1$

Comment: @Richard: Yes, if there’s an alien who knows all of the others. And if there isn’t, the possible numbers that a single alien could know are $0,1,\dots,n-2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

There are $N$ aliens, and assume one of the alien knows $K$ aliens. $(N>K)$

Can each alien know **distinct** number of aliens?

Assume $A_1$ knows ${A_2,A_3 \dots A_{K+1}}$, now that $A_2$ knows $K$ aliens, the aliens who he knows also knows him.(Though confusing, its the fact -evil laugh-)

Answer (score 0):

An alien can know between $0$ and $n-1$ aliens. That is $n$ possibilities. If one alien knows everyone else, then there is no one who doesn't know any one. And the other way around. So possibilities $0$ and $n-1$ are mutually exclusive. So we are down to $n-1$ possibilities for each alien to know others.

So if there are $n$ aliens and $n-1$ possibilities of knowing others, with then at least $2$ aliens exist who know the same number of aliens on the spaceship.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

suppose there are 10 aliens for example .
alien 1 knows alien 2 , how many aliens does 2 know now ?? for the hypothesis to be false alien 2 already knows alien 1 and for him not to know just 1 lets assume he knows alien 3 thus knows 2 .
same for alien 3 , he must know 3 .. continueing onward when we get to alien 10 he knows 10  aliens but since he cant count himself thats a contradiction hence 2 aliens know same number of aliens .

Answer (score 0):

consider lattice points in the plane. an example is say there are 4 aliens. just like a dice these 4 dots must have two lines or else two aliens would Know O others.  then suppose 1 alien knows 1 other and the other 3 must know a different number of the aliens left . this means one dot will have 2 lines , one will have 3 and in all we would have 1,2,3, lines respectively. Its clear then these lines will connect to the other dots hence a contradiction. the case of n=4 , n=5 ect can be generalized to saying N dots must have only (n-1)n/2 lines but this sum by pigeonhole means 2 aliens will thus have the same number of lines connected to them.